# Share contact group

Tags: ios, contacts

My wife and I have shared calendar groups and reminders lists (both requires using icloud.com website) for things like travel, parties, and grocery list.

I would love to do the same with contact group, but can't figure out how.

As a workaround, we are using a shared iCloud account for (1) sharing contact groups, (2) Find My iPhone, and (3) app/music/video/book purchases.

Comment: I'm confused.  You're using iCloud to share contacts, but you want to find a way to share your contacts.  It sounds like you're already have what you need.  What's missing?  Or what don't you like about your current solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, open Address Book, select a group of contacts, and then click on the Export button in the menubar. Then export it as a vCard, and email it to anyone you want.

Comment: I am looking for more "live" (automatic) sharing solution. Using another shared iCloud account does exactly that, but at the expense of having to manage multiple accounts.